# jQuery - Passing variable within a function to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a few different functions that set a variable if the user clicks on a certain button. It then passes that variable on to an AJAX function....except it doesn't pass the variable.

Here is an example:

```
$('#Button1').on('click', function(e) {
    var add1 = 'yes';
    e.preventdefault();
})
$('#Button2').on('click', function(e) {
    var add1 = 'no';
    e.preventdefault();
})
$('#DoneButton').on('click', function(e) {
    submitLink = 'submit.php'
    dataString = 'add=' + add1;
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: submitLink,
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function(data) {

           /* My Success Notification Here */
       }
    });
    e.preventdefault();
})
```

I also tried declaring the variable outside of the function as:

```
var add1;
```

That doesn't work either, just comes up as 'undefined'

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: because adding the `var` makes it locally scoped to the onclick

Comment: What can I do to make it so all the other functions can fetch it? @epascarello

Comment: don't use `var` ...  Just set it .. `Myvar = 'blah'`;

Comment: Wow...didn't think it was that easy haha. Thanks! That fixed my issue @epascarello

Answer (score 3, accepted):

drop the `var` inside so the variable reference is not locally scoped to the click.

```
var add1;
$('#Button1').on('click', function(e) {
  add1 = 'yes';
  e.preventdefault();
})
$('#Button2').on('click', function(e) {
  add1 = 'no';
  e.preventdefault();
})
$('#DoneButton').on('click', function(e) {
  submitLink = 'submit.php'
  dataString = 'add=' + add1;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: submitLink,
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

      /* My Success Notification Here */
    }
  });
  e.preventdefault();
});
```

Comment: Perfect, didn't think it was that easy haha. This fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Putting `var add1` in the function declares it locally in that function. If you want to declare it outside, you have to add `var add1;` outside the function, and then remove the `var`s inside the function, ie `add1 = 'no';

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable in the shared scope so that all the functions can access it, in this case that's the global scope. Then assign a value to it inside the local scope of the function.

The simple part you were missing is that once you've declared it in the shared scope using `var myVar`, you don't need to use the `var` keyword again when assigning to it, because doing so creates a different variable only accessible in the local scope of the function, regardless of whether it has the same name.