# Moving $.get method to its own function to avoid repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have the following function for pulling data from a php json_encode for use in FullCalendar.

```
    eventDrop: function(info) {
    $.get( "php/get-events.php", function( data ) {
    // data is your result
    // Find the value for editable where the event id = the event you are trying to move 
    rawdata = JSON.parse(data);
    editable = rawdata.find(x => x.id === info.event.id).editable;
   start= info.event.start.toISOString();
   start = moment(info.event.start).format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
   end= info.event.end.toISOString();
   end = moment(info.event.end).format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
   title = info.event.title;
   id = info.event.id;
    });
   }
```

I will use very similar code for the eventResize function within fullcalendar, so I would like to extract this part

```
 $.get( "php/get-events.php", function( data ) {
    // data is your result
    // Find the value for editable where the event id = the event you are trying to move 
    rawdata = JSON.parse(data);
```

into it's own function (not 100% sure I'm using the right terminology here?) I seen this answer [jQuery - Passing variable within a function to another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819460/jquery-passing-variable-within-a-function-to-another-function) about how to pass variables in the global scope, so I tried to move my above code out of eventDrop like so

```
$.get( "php/get-events.php", function( data ) {
    // data is your result
    // Find the value for editable where the event id = the event you are trying to move 
    rawdata = JSON.parse(data);
});
   eventDrop: function(info) {
```

But this gives me an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

Ideally I would like to do the json extract using the $.get only one time throughout my page, and then reference the rawdata global variable to read the information, is this possible?

My full solution at current is

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var today = moment().day();
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
      },
      defaultDate: today,
      editable: true,
      
    $.get( "php/get-events.php", function( data ) {
    // data is your result
    // Find the value for editable where the event id = the event you are trying to move 
    rawdata = JSON.parse(data);
    });

    eventDrop: function(info) {
    editable = rawdata.find(x => x.id === info.event.id).editable;
   start= info.event.start.toISOString();
   start = moment(info.event.start).format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
   end= info.event.end.toISOString();
   end = moment(info.event.end).format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
   title = info.event.title;
   id = info.event.id;
   if (!confirm("Confirm you want to change " + info.event.title + " to " + info.event.start)) {
      info.revert();
    }
    else{
      if(editable === 'Y'){
        $.ajax({
        url: 'php/calendarupdate.php',
        data: 'title=' + info.event.title + '&start='+ start +'&end=' + end + '&id=' + info.event.id ,
        type: "POST"
        });
      } 
      else{
        alert("Can only modify this calendar event if you created it. Please ask the event creator to modify.");
        calendar.refetchEvents();
      }
    }

   
   },

      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: {
        url: '/php/get-events.php',
        failure: function() {
          document.getElementById('script-warning').style.display = 'block'
        }
      },
      loading: function(bool) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display =
          bool ? 'block' : 'none';
      }
    });

    calendar.render();
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Could you please post a complete code example. It's hard to understand the full context from the individual snippets - or even where that error is coming from as none of the examples shown will cause that.

Comment: It looks like you extracted your get call into the middle of your object literal, eg `{prop:value,$.get(...),otherprop:value}` that isnt valid syntax hence the error.

Comment: Please post complete code example of when you put `$.get` code outside and trying to use it's output in other 2 functions.

Comment: Sorry folks, didn't know if you wanted the long block of text code, I added that into the main post at the end there thanks. I think Patrick is right and it's inserted in the wrong place, but I'm not really too sure where to put it, I've tried a few places and got the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, thanks to @Patrick Evans for the suggestion, I was adding the get call to the middle of my code, where I had to add it at the end, after the ";" to end the line. I can now reference "rawdata" variable within EventDrop.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var today = moment().day();
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
      },
      defaultDate: today,
      editable: true,
      
    eventDrop: function(info) {
    editable = rawdata.find(x => x.id === info.event.id).editable;
   start= info.event.start.toISOString();
   start = moment(info.event.start).format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
   end= info.event.end.toISOString();
   end = moment(info.event.end).format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
   title = info.event.title;
   id = info.event.id;
   if (!confirm("Confirm you want to change " + info.event.title + " to " + info.event.start)) {
      info.revert();
    }
    else{
      if(editable === 'Y'){
        $.ajax({
        url: 'php/calendarupdate.php',
        data: 'title=' + info.event.title + '&start='+ start +'&end=' + end + '&id=' + info.event.id ,
        type: "POST"
        });
      } 
      else{
        alert("Can only modify this calendar event if you created it. Please ask the event creator to modify.");
        calendar.refetchEvents();
      }
    } 
   },
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: {
        url: '/php/get-events.php',
        failure: function() {
          document.getElementById('script-warning').style.display = 'block'
        }
      },
      loading: function(bool) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display =
          bool ? 'block' : 'none';
      }
    });
    $.get( "php/get-events.php", function( data ) {
    // data is your result
    // Find the value for editable where the event id = the event you are trying to move 
    rawdata = JSON.parse(data);
    });

    calendar.render();
  });

</script>
```